# Linux sort and make unique text not by entire line but string position

Tags: sed, awk

Is there a way to sort a text file in Linux (GNU) like CSV or whatever not by line (sort | uniq) but by string position. Example:

```
John Doe|Something|c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b|Blah Blah
John Smith|Nothing|c81e728d9d4c2f636f067f89cc14862c|Blah Blah
Johanna Doe|Another thing|c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b|Blah Blah
J Doe|Does not matter|eccbc87e4b5ce2fe28308fd9f2a7baf3|Blah Blah
```

so is there a way using common GNU tools like sed, awk, cut... to get this output:

```
John Doe|Something|c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b|Blah Blah
John Smith|Nothing|c81e728d9d4c2f636f067f89cc14862c|Blah Blah
J Doe|Does not matter|eccbc87e4b5ce2fe28308fd9f2a7baf3|Blah Blah
```

the md5 hash (in this case) must be unique not the other data.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sort -u -t\| -k3,3 input-file.txt
```

Explanation of arguments:

- `-u`: Unique records
- `-t\|`: Set the field delimiter to `|` (the backslash is used to escape the `|` so it is not processed as a pipe by the shell)
- `-k3,3`: Use the 3rd column (and only the 3rd column) as the sort key